# Should I start using boost as a C++ Beginner?

Tags: c++, boost

I have been learning C++ from Thinking in C++- Bruce Eckel and usually I have to take SO's help to clear some of my doubts . Of late, I have been going through stuffs dealing with smart pointers, postfix and prefic overloading and overloading other operators like -> and ->* which seemed to be a hard nut for me to get hold of. Thus, while going through a SO question about the dynamics of overloading ->* operator , I came to know a lot about smart pointers and thus a new library called boost. Now, is it feasible and constructive for me to start using that library when I am just getting hold of good C++ knowledge because it provides a lot of good different things like shared_pointers etc which aren't directly available in C++ standard libraries apart from many other optimizations and functions or I should just stick stick to the basics of Eckel and later go looking for boost. Also I would like to know something more about the boost library (the good things and the bad things involved in using it). Thanks in advance

Comment: There is actually a `std::shared_ptr` (and more) in C++11.

Comment: Why would you be overloading `->*`, as a *beginner* in C++?

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes , its given in Eckel and I hate skipping anything while going through good reading .

Comment: @KavishDwivedi: OK, let's try another question. Why are you reading a book from *thirteen years ago*?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Most of my seniors recommended this reference apart from the fact that its the most widely followed reference in IITs and NITs in India. Now that I am almost into the last 3-4 chapters , would it be wiser to switch the reference alltogether?

Comment: Alot of the stuff in boost is in the new c++ standard and implemented in the more recent compilers. Learn your basics first and then look into these features. Just don't rely on very old books to provide accuracy to todays standards.

Comment: My 2 cents are that you can't master concepts if you use a library where you don't really have to deal with them, so don't use STL, Boost or really any library too much until you're really comfortable with just vanilla C++ (or at least the applicable concepts of the library functionality you want to use).

Comment: @NicolBolas: One thing more out of the topic. I am a naive game developer and use Pygame. I just started with pyopengl and would like to take some tips from you if you could give me your email id or any other feasible contact.You seem to be an experienced in this field :)

Comment: @Dukeling I disagree. There is for example absolutely no good reason to ever having to bother with the horrible vanilla C++ integer parsing capabilities (something that will come up in lots of easy problems to deal with). Vanilla C++ is missing hundreds of essential things and while it's fun to reimplement all of them, he may actually want to get something useful done instead of reimplementing e.g. his own (broken) XML parser.

Comment: @Voo If you ever want to work as a C++ developer, you'll most likely have to be able to maintain or write code that doesn't use a library at some point. Thus decent knowledge of vanilla C++ is good. Not to mention the massive benefit to your coding ability implementing some complex stuff Boost or a similar library will usually take care of will give. And no, I'm not really talking about implementing something as complex as an XML parser (though thinking that through would definitely be good) or taking working under deadlines into account.

Comment: "STL" **is** vanilla C++. Has been that way since 1998.

Comment: @Dukeling boost is pretty prevalent (and I don't think I ever worked on a project that didn't use the STL) ime and for good reasons. I assume if you're working with 30 year old mainframe code, then yes I assume beginners should learn all about manual memory management, implementing their own lists with macros and pointer manipulation (well, that and COBOL), but otherwise I'm pretty happy if they learn how to use smartpointers, STL containers, etc. instead. In the end that will result in happier programmers and better code.. win/win.

Comment: If they later want to implement their own AVL or red-black trees they can always go ahead, it's a fun, academic and in practice utterly useless thing (I implemented basically every datastructure in CLRS and more back in University and I think the most complicated one I ever implemented in a real project was a tree for ranges). On the other hand figuring out how to use a HTML/XML parser library has been useful in dozens of little side projects and in more than one job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by others, I would take a look at what's newly available in C++11 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11.

Boost itself is a huge library so it would really depend on which specific part of boost you had planned to make use of.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, try to get a good grasp of the language first

Answer (score 0):

there are libraries (like QuantLib) that uses boost extensively. I think you can start to learn it faster than you think you think you can/should.

you may want to look at this [introduction to selected boost classes](http://quantlib.org/slides/dima-boost-intro.pdf)